# RequireJS: same module with different names

Tags: build, requirejs, r.js

Is it possible to use the same module under different names in RequireJS? (Mostly interested in optimized version)

**Example**

I depend on an AMD-compatible library that depends on `lodash`. I already have `underscore` in my code and I want that library to use it instead of `lodash`.

Of course I do not want modify library's source. So I modify the require.js configuration:

```
paths: {
  'underscore': 'vendor/underscore', // that's for my code
  ...
  'lodash': 'vendor/underscore', // that's for the new library
}
```

And now when trying to build, r.js throws the unfortunate:

```
The following modules share the same URL. 
This could be a misconfiguration if that URL only has one anonymous module in it:
   /.../underscore.js: lodash, underscore
```

Is there a way to register the same module under 2 or more different names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it is not safe to load Underscore for code that requires Lodash. The one exception is if you are 100% sure that the code in question used Lodash in its Underscore-compatible mode.

If you have determined that it is safe in your specific case, then I would handle your specific problem by using a `map`:

```
map: {
    "*": { 'lodash': 'underscore'}
}
```

This tells RequireJS that everywhere `lodash` is required, give back `underscore` instead.

The method above returns a *single* module instance if `lodash` or `underscore` are required. It would not work in a case someone would want to load the same module code twice under two different names and would want to keep *module state* separate. For instance, a module which is meant to register names. If someone would want to load this module under names `foo` and `bar` and keep the two registries *separate* so that what is registered in `foo` is but not registered in `bar` is not in `bar` (and vice-versa) then they would need two module instances and thus would have to do something else than use `map`.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine, exactly what I was looking for. Alhough it seems to me that this way to configure things is a bit weird, but this is offtopic :)